# Как изменить данное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

[Есть регулярное выражение:](https://regex101.com/r/1oW5x7/1)

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)$
```

Как его модифицировать, чтобы не позволять плавающий `/` в конце, например, для такой логики:

```
https://regex101.com ПОДХОДИТ
https://regex101.com/test ПОДХОДИТ
https://regex101.com/ НЕ ПОДХОДИТ
```

Пробовал добавить в конец `[^\/]$`, но это не помогает почему-то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте негативный блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!\/)` в конце:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*)$(?<!\/)
```

Или негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!.*\/$)` в начале

```
^(?!.*\/$)https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*)$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/1oW5x7/2).